Show that if $n$ is a Fermat pseudoprime to the base $a$, then $n$ and $a$ are relatively prime.
I am trying to prove the following theorem:
If $n$ is a Fermat Pseudoprime to the base $a$ then $n$ and $a$ are relatively prime.
As a recap a Fermat Pseudoprime $n$ has the property that for $n$ not being prime if for all $a$ such that $2\leq a \leq n-1$ $$a^{n-1}\equiv 1\,\, (mod\, n)$$
I tried it in a following way but am not sure if it is correct. I tried by using the proof by contrapositive method:
If $n$ and $a$ are not relatively prime then either $n>a$ or $n\leq a$.
In the first case I can then write $n=\alpha a$. Now we need to show that $$a^{n-1}\neq 1 (mod \, n)$$
Clearly $$n\nmid a^{n-1}-1$$
because that is the same as saying:
$$\alpha a\nmid  a^{n-1}-1$$
here the second term is not a whole number so therefore $n$ cannot be a pseudoprime.
For the second case:
$a=\alpha n$
In that case we have to show again that $$a^{n-1}\neq 1 (mod \, n)$$ or written differently:
$$(\alpha n)^{n-1}\neq 1 (mod \, n)$$
Thus again
$$n\nmid  (\alpha n)^{n-1}-1$$ because the second term is not a whole number.
Is this proof correct?

If $n,|,(a^{n-1}-1)$ then of course $\gcd(a,n)=1$ (any common divisor would also divide $1$).  As a formatting note: \nmid looks a lot better than \not |.  It's $\nmid$ vs $\not |$.

@lulu okay yes that's a lot simpler than what I did. I didn't see that somehow.

There's a much simpler way to prove the theorem as mentioned by lulu in the comments.
Since we have $$a^{n-1}\equiv 1 (mod\, n)$$
We have $$n|a^{n-1}-1$$
Then we can write:
$$a^{n-1}-1=\alpha n$$
Rearranging:
$$(a^{n-2})a+(-\alpha) n=1$$
this means that $gcd(n,a)=1$ and since we know that n is not a prime number $n$ and $a$ must be relatively prime.
